# What is the difference between MD5CryptoServiceProvider and HMACMD5

Tags: c#, cryptography

In C#,What is the difference between HMACMD5() and MD5CryptoServiceProvider()?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacmd5(v=vs.110).aspx  and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is a cryptographic hash function. [HMACMD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) is a message authentication code, a keyed hash function which uses MD5.